# I want to be able to create a data frame, with NULLS using results in lists that have an inconsistent list size

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I want to be able to create a data frame using results in lists that have an inconsistent list size. I want to display "NULL", "N/A" or "0" where there is no data.

These are my column names

```
header = ['Group','Person in charge', 'Type of Service', 'Registered Care Categories*', 'Shared Rooms','Facilities & Service']
```

The first element in each 2 element list for results and results1 corresponds to the name of the column shown in headers.

```
results = [['Group', 'MacIntyre'],['Person in charge', ' Vivienne Donald (Manager)'], 
           ['Type of Service', 'good'],['Shared Rooms', '4']]

results1 = [['Group', 'Jameseson'], ['Type of Service', 'bad'],['Shared Rooms', '8']]
```

Desired Output: Table image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing one way to accomplish what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

# first, construct a dataframe containing your desired columns
columns = ['Group', 'Person in charge', 'Type of Service', 
           'Registered Care Categories*', 'Shared Rooms', 'Facilities & Service']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# then, store each of your results in a list, so that they can be iterated through
result1 = [['Group', 'MacIntyre'], ['Person in charge', ' Vivienne Donald (Manager)'],
           ['Type of Service', 'good'], ['Shared Rooms', '4']]

result2 = [['Group', 'Jameseson'], ['Type of Service', 'bad'], ['Shared Rooms', '8']]

results = [result1, result2]

# now, loop through your results using enumerate to create an index for that dataframe row
for index, result in enumerate(results):
    # within each result, loop through the available data elements 
    for item in result:
        # unpack the items in the list
        column, value = item[0], item[1]
        # store the value in the appropriate columns
        df.loc[index, column] = value

# finally, inspect the dataframe
print(df)
```